# How to reference a user defined exsheets environment using cleveref

Tags: cleveref, exsheets

I have defined an environment in `exsheets` package and want to cite it using `cleveref` package and am not able to find a way. I tried many things and tried to read the `exsheets` manual. I searched also. May be the solution is available in the manual or the internet, but I couldn't find. Help required.

Following is the code (not working) which I hope should be self explanatory.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\NewQuSolPair{example}[name=Example,headings=runin]{egsolution}[name=Solution,print=true,headings=runin]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample chapter}
This is some text.
\begin{example}\label{ex:test}
  This is some example.
\end{example}
\begin{egsolution}
  This is the solution.
\end{egsolution}
This is some example \cref{ex:test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `exsheets` package still does not allow to use another counter than `question` (as far as I know, although I asked @clemens about this to change ;-))

However, `cleveref` does not know the label type `question`, so

`\crefname{question}{question}{questions}` and the upper case variant

`\Crefname{question}{Question}{Questions}` have to be defined later on.

`cleveref` should also be one of the packages that are loaded in the last place, i.e. after `exsheets` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\NewQuSolPair{example}[name=Example,headings=runin]{egsolution}[name=Solution,print=true,headings=runin]
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
\Crefname{question}{Question}{Questions}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample chapter}
This is some text.
\begin{example}\label{ex:test}
  This is some example.
\end{example}
\begin{egsolution}
  This is the solution.
\end{egsolution}


This is some example \cref{ex:test}. \Cref{ex:test} shows that ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I am not too happy about `\NewQuSolPair` and have thought about dropping it…

Comment: @clemens: If I ever find time to publish my own `arbeitsblatt` package it will have a similar `environment` defining command (I did not know that your package has such a command)

Comment: @AbhinavPratapSingh:You're welcome. Happy TeXing!